# How to load a large file into a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm writing a script in bash and would like to load a large file /var/log/syslog into a mysql table with the datatype longblob.

```
string=$(</var/log/syslog)
mysql --user=username --password=passwd123 databasename << EOF
insert into table (column) values (LOAD_FILE('$string'));
```

I can't make it work, in the table in mysql it only shows "NULL"

I'm going to load the content from the database in mysql to a website afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `LOAD DATA INFILE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html .

Comment: Thanks! I also had to change the ownership of the file to mysql